# Logging filesystems: Can someone explain how an "undo log" is supposed to work as opposed to a "redo log"?

Tags: filesystems, logging

I know how redo logs and their commits are supposed to work, but I was wondering if anyone knew how the undo log itself works as well... is it supposed to be a faster way to do logging as opposed to redo log? Or do they both have drawbacks that the other does not?

Comment: I think the log (or journal) is for both redoing and undoing?

Comment: You just don't overwrite material.  Like Hansel and Gretel.